# div not displaying in centre of page

Tags: html, css

i have this css code:

```
#header-topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
#header-right-content {
    float:right;
    margin-right:14%;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#000000;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#logo-small {
    display:none;
}
```

and then this for my responsive css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    #header-right-content {
            display:none;
    }
    #logo {
        display:block;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 25px;
        width: 360px;
        height: 50px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
}
```

and then the HTML:

```
<div id="header-topbar">
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="360" height="50" /></div>
<div id="header-right-content"><?php
if($_SESSION["customer_loggedin"] == 'yes')
{
    echo 'Hello '.$_SESSION["customer_forename"].' '.$_SESSION["customer_surname"].' | <a href="/customer/index.php">Customer Centre</a> | <a href="/customer/logout.php">Logout</a>';
}
else
{
    echo '<a href="/customer/login.php">Customer Login</a>';
}
?><br /><br />
Tel: <?php echo $main_phone_number; ?><br />Email: <?php echo $company_emailaddress_sales; ?></div> <!-- header-right-content -->
</div>
```

for some reason, as the screen gets smaller i cannot get the logo to display right in the centre of the page. the div #logo will not centre in the page.

any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Made a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6Wp4/

Comment: its displaying ok on a fiddle though which is odd

Comment: @charliejsford: no it's not.  Stretch out the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an absolute positioned div use left and margin-left to center it:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    #header-right-content {
        display:none;
    }
    #logo {
        display:block;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 25px;
        width: 360px;
        height: 50px;
        border:1px solid black;
        left: 50%; //this centers the left side of the div to the page
        margin-left: -180px; //this subtracts half the width to center it on the page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float:left;` does exactly that.  It floats the element to the left.  Do you want the `<img>` tag to center in the `#logo` element, or the `#logo` element to center within it's parent element?

If you want to center a `div` element, use `margin: 0 auto;`.

```
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px auto 0;
  width: 360px;
  height: 50px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Also, this is an extremely standard practice and simple solution that you should have been able to find on your own, even on this site where it's been asked countless times.  I will not flag people for questions like this, but a lot of people on this site would.  Too many flags gets you banned from asking anymore questions, so be sure to research it thoroughly before posting questions on here.

Comment: well the #logo div element can just be centered as the image it just the same width as the #div element. i just want the logo to be right in the middle when the screen is shrunk as far as it will go